# Ubuntu 14.04 default logon

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu 14.04 in Vmware what is the default login?  How would I find the password?  What is Ubuntu designed to do?

Comment: What is Ubuntu designed to do? http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? This seems to be a pretty legitimate query from new users. Although, yes, the last part should be a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no default login.**

If you have not installed it to the hard disk, (i.e. 'Live' mode or you chose 'Try Ubuntu'), then there *is* no password.

But if you (or someone else) set it up, then there *must* be a password. If somebody else did, ask them.

> What is Ubuntu designed to do?

Ubuntu is designed to provide a free, open source and powerful computing platform, as an alternative to proprietary OSes like Mac OS X or Windows.

Ubuntu uses the Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org) and is based on [Debian](http://debian.org). It is heavily inspired by Unix.